# I want to override some properties of the ToolStripButton control in a derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance, controls

i am trying to make a derived `ToolStripButton` class named `ToolStripButtonEx`. I want to change the default values of the properties `DisplayStyle` and `Text`.

This is my code so far:

```
[ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability(ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability.All)]
public class ToolStripButtonEx : ToolStripButton
{
    [DefaultValue(ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Text)]
    ToolStripItemDisplayStyle _DisplayStyle;
    [DefaultValue(ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Text)]
    public new ToolStripItemDisplayStyle DisplayStyle { get => _DisplayStyle; set => _DisplayStyle = value; }
    [DefaultValue("BlaBlub")]
    string _Text;
    [DefaultValue("BlaBlub")]
    public new string Text { get => _Text; set => _Text = value; }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.Clear(Color.PapayaWhip);
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
    public ToolStripButtonEx() : base()
    {
        this.DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Text;
    }
    public ToolStripButtonEx(String text) : base(text)
    {
        this.DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Text;
    }
    public ToolStripButtonEx(Image image) : base(image)
    {
        this.DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Text;
    }
    public ToolStripButtonEx(String text, Image image) : base(text, image)
    {
        this.DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Text;
    }
    public ToolStripButtonEx(String text, Image image, EventHandler onClick) : base(text, image, onClick)
    {
        this.DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Text;
    }
    public ToolStripButtonEx(String text, Image image, EventHandler onClick, String name) : base(text,image,onClick,name)
    {
        this.DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Text;
    }
}
```

My expectation now is, when i add this ToolStripButtonEx item to a toolstrip, that the `DisplayStyle` and `Text` properties are set to the default values as given in my class.

But it does not work. The overriden Paint event does work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Set these properties in constructor ;)

Comment: I did: `this.DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Text;`